# .htaccess rewrite imgname.jpg to image.php?img=imgname

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am attempting to rewrite URLs like the following:

```
domain.com/news/12/imgname.jpg
```

to

```
domain.com/image.php?img=12/imgname
```

I am using the following in my .htaccess file, but it does not seem to be working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+\/.*)\.jpg$ image.php?img=$1 [L]
```

Can anyone help me see what I've done wrong?

Comment: What's not working? Do you get a error 500 or similar, or does it just do nothing?

Comment: You are checking that the request matches *an existing file* before re-writing it - are your images stored in `wwwroot/NN/imagename.type`?

Comment: It just not working. No redirection. No errors.

Comment: all images stored in domain.com/news/[1-99]/someimgname.jpg

Comment: Does calling domain.com/image.php?img=12/imgname directly work?

Answer (score 0):

You should not escape the forward slash. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+/.*)\.jpg$ /image.php?img=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This should not make any difference; mod_rewrite uses PCRE regexps, in which both `/` and `\/` match a forward slash.

Comment: Well it worked in http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ - which does not mean it works in every environment. If you are right, however, the rewrite should work.

Comment: Please try RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.jpg$ /image.php?img=$1/$2 [L], which should definitely work. If not, you have another kind of error.

Comment: I try it before and now too and not working.

Answer (score 0):

Does your .htaccess file contain an appropriate [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive?  If not, add the following line before your rewrite rules:

```
RewriteBase /
```

You should also make sure you've enabled the mod_rewrite engine with:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks<br>
  RewriteEngine On<br>
  RewriteBase /<br>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f<br>
  RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+/.*)\.jpg$ /image.php?img=$1 [L]<br><br>

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on<br>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]<br>
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]<br><br>

Options -MultiViews<br><br>Still not working

Comment: OK, so that's not it.  Next questions: 1) does your rewrite rule work if you comment out the `RewriteCond`, and 2) if not, do _any_ rewrite rules actually work?

Comment: Pasting code into comments doesn't work very well. It's better to edit your question and include the code there. (Then again, in this, case, a simple "yes, I already use `RewriteBase /`" would've been enough.)

Comment: OK Thanks. It still not working and i don't understand Why. It must work.